# com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException when deploying into WAS8.5.5?

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, websphere-8

I have developed one web-services application using spring boot and when i am trying to deploy it into WebSphere 8.5.5 then it throws following exception.

```
[9/22/14 1:24:54:194 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[9/22/14 1:24:54:194 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/Users/ac99534/WebSpher8.5.5_Instal/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/VDAASW700793Node02Cell/soa-clm-hipaa-inq-ear.ear/soa-clm-hipaa-inq-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[9/22/14 1:24:54:194 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://267.fwk-19140409:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[9/22/14 1:24:54:195 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[9/22/14 1:24:54:287 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
[9/22/14 1:24:55:020 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: Could not initialize logging from classpath:org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/basic-logback.xml
[9/22/14 1:24:55:022 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:022 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:023 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:023 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:023 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:023 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:023 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:023 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:023 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:024 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:446)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:024 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:024 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:024 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:117)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:024 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:664)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:024 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:024 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:025 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:025 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:678)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:025 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:622)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:025 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:025 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:026 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:026 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:026 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:026 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:026 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:026 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:027 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:027 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:027 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:027 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:027 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:027 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:027 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:027 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:028 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:028 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:028 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:028 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:028 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:028 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:028 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:241)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:029 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:578)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:029 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:029 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:029 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:029 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:029 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:029 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:030 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:030 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:030 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:030 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:030 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:030 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:047 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:047 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:048 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:048 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:048 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:048 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:048 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:049 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:049 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:049 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:049 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:049 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:049 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:050 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:050 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:050 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:050 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:050 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:050 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:064 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:064 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:064 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:064 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:065 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:065 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:065 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:065 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:065 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:065 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:065 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:066 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:066 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:066 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:066 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:068 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:068 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:068 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:069 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:069 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:069 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:069 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:069 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:069 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:069 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: Could not initialize logging from classpath:org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/basic-logback.xml
[9/22/14 1:24:55:070 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:759)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:071 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:071 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:071 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  ... 97 more
[9/22/14 1:24:55:071 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Could not initialize logging from classpath:org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/basic-logback.xml
[9/22/14 1:24:55:072 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:176)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:072 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:746)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:072 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  ... 99 more
[9/22/14 1:24:55:073 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize logging from classpath:org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/basic-logback.xml
[9/22/14 1:24:55:073 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:104)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:073 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSensibleDefaults(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:62)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:073 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:45)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:073 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:69)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:073 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:135)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:073 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:074 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:074 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:074 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:276)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:074 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:074 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:89)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:075 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:51)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:075 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:075 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:613)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:075 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:075 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:075 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:075 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  ... 100 more
[9/22/14 1:24:55:075 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Parser configuration error occurred
[9/22/14 1:24:55:076 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:88)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:076 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.recordEvents(SaxEventRecorder.java:59)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:076 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:134)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:076 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:99)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:077 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:49)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:079 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:079 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:101)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:079 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  ... 116 more
[9/22/14 1:24:55:079 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
[9/22/14 1:24:55:080 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
[9/22/14 1:24:55:080 CDT] 00000097 SystemErr     R  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder.buildSaxParser(SaxEventRecorder.java:81)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Make sure that you haven't included XML api jars in your war and you also might want to set class loading to parent last on websphere.

Comment: Yes i want to set cass loading to parent last on websphere

Comment: Then as M. Deinum said, you must ensure that either you do not include the javax.xml API jars in your WAR or that you have included a full XML parser implementation in your WAR.